# CSTheory Blog Announcement and Signup Sheet

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog

> July 21st: The first technical post is now up, [Quantum query complexity](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/quantum-query-complexity/), by Artem Kaznatcheev.
>
> July 16th: The first blog post is now up, [here](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/welcome-to-the-theoretical-computer-science-community-blog/).

This is not so much a question as an announcement and a request for participation. We now have a cstheory blog at cstheory.blogoverflow.com !

We'll have to feel out the best way to use it to augment the discussions on the site. To start with, we are happy to announce two editors-in-chief of the blog. [Joe Fitzsimons](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/204/joe-fitzsimons) and [Aaron Sterling](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/30/aaron-sterling) have agreed to manage content on the blog, and among their roles will be soliciting posts from YOU to place there.

Which brings me to the second point. As currently envisaged (Joe and Aaron will have more to say on this I'm sure), anyone who's interested can contribute to the blog, and this is how it would work:

1. you write a draft on the site
2. An editor reviews it
3. It gets posted.

Presumably as time goes on, some contributors might get direct posting rights - we can see how that goes.

So what should you do now ? Sign up if you're interested in contributing. To do so, post your name and/or a link to your profile, which hopefully has an email address, in an answer below, and one of the admins (Kaveh or myself) will create an account for you.

Once that's done, you can start writing drafts. And I'm sure the editors will nudge people as well.

If you have questions about the format, content styles etc, please create a new meta question and link it here. Let's keep this post primarily for signups.

Comment: Great idea! I feel like we should have a weekly/monthly/quarterly digest there feature the best questions/answers of the resp period.

Comment: I assume the blog will have the same scope as the SE, i.e. research level TCS? Are you aiming at results, questions, errors, ...?

Comment: depends on the editors. We're discussing this in chat right now

Comment: Instead of asking people to publish their email, once they've indicated they'd like an account you can pull it from their profile.

Comment: good point, Rebecca. I changed it

Comment: it would be great if it can be added to the theory of computing blog aggregator

Comment: @AaronSterling, you should receive an email for your blog account, let me know if you don't get it.

Comment: It hasn't arrived yet......

Comment: aaron, check your spam folder. the invitation has already gone out (I checked).

Comment: Kaveh sent a second invite to an alternate email address so I got in that way.  Thanks, Kaveh.

Comment: I had a question about [latex support](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1203/1037) and [length/style](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1205/1037) for those of starting to write posts.

Comment: Awesome ! blog up and running now.

Comment: Rebecca just pointed out that [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) also works on the blog. :)

Comment: @Suresh, it seems that Aug 16th cstheory will complete its first year. Would be nice if write a blog post for the event? :)

Comment: That's a great idea. @Joe, Aaron any thoughts on what we should do ? I could write something about the whole process of setting up the site ?

Comment: Suresh and @Kaveh: Great idea. I missed the start of the site (I committed but wasn't around for the definition phase). Who were involved right from the start?

Comment: @Joe Fitzsimons: [precognitive](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/badges/62/precognitive), [beta](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta), [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8766?phase=definition). Also there are some posts on Suresh's blog and a discussion on MO meta.

Comment: btw I may have misread @Kaveh's original comment: if you'd like to write the post, please go ahead.

Comment: @Suresh: no, you have read it correctly, I had no intention of writing it. (I just saw that there is typo in my comment, there should be a "you" before write :)

Comment: I'll start a new meta thread to solicit ideas.

Answer (score 10):

I would be interested in giving short introductions to topological quantum computation and the basics of quantum computation.

Comment: Thanks very much. That sounds great.

Comment: I agree. Why not write something up once one of the mods has set up your account?

Comment: invitation has been sent !

Comment: Sounds great!  Thanks.

Comment: I will try to write something on the weekend. I will adapt my talks to a blog form. Thanks for adding me.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to contribute. To start I will probably submit a post about the (negative) adversary method and quantum query complexity.

Comment: invitation sent. :)

Comment: Hey maybe we can check each others blog posts before we post them? We seem to have slightly similar topics.

Comment: Thanks very much, Artem.

Comment: Sure thing, I can see your draft (the title and a snippet) in the dashboard, but I can't actual view the post to read it. I probably don't have the correct privileges. Joe Fitzsimons is also a quantum guy, so I am sure his editorial reading will be of more help than mine, but I am happy to do a sanity check (since I am know very little about topological QC).

Comment: Please feel free to communicate by email as much or as little as you'd like.  If you are concerned about potential duplication, please post at least a thesis statement as a draft in the blog, and Joe will make a determination when he is back online.  (This may not be for a day or two, and I would prefer to defer to him in all things quantum, so don't be concerned if it takes us a while to respond to this.)

Answer (score 5):

I'd be interested in posting from time to time, but I'm not sure what is appropriate -- I already have [my own blog](http://semantic-domain.blogspot.com), but I don't know how much of it would be of interest to this audience.

Comment: I remember being quite interested in the connection to metric spaces that you outlined once. In addition, even a generic "question of the week in formal methods" would be great. the "audience" for the blog should be broader than the active membership, and that would include a lot of folk in the theory B community I'd hope.

Comment: Neel, you should have received an activation email at your gmail acct. check in case it disappeared into spam.

Comment: Just speaking for myself -- I have not discussed this with Joe yet -- I would enjoy a level of exposition a half-step *more basic* than the current Theory B answers.  General idea: take a great Theory B answer, or question, and introduce the background, philosophically what is at stake, general reason the answer is true, and then for full technical details, link to the answer. A general-TCS-person's introduction to Theory B.

Comment: @Neel: I would also definitely be interested. I think in getting the blog going having something that is slightly more basic than the standard on the Q&A site would be great initially, and would perhaps set the stage for future posts on the topic.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to contribute too at some point.

Comment: Great!  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

I am interested! For example, I recently wrote a short blogicle about something related to geometry and optimization -- http://daveagp.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/depth-and-violation/ -- or I could give a report on EuroComb and ESA in the next few weeks.

Comment: Done. I've created an account for you, and you should be getting a confirmation email at the address you've listed in your profile page. As for the actual content, please discuss with Joe and Aaron.

Comment: Everything you mention sounds great.  Reports on those conferences, in particular, would fill a longstanding gap in the TCS blogosphere.  I've seen (semi-)daily reports on FOCS, STOC, SODA, ICS/ITCS, and PODC, but that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I'd be interested in contributing. But starting from September, as I'll be too busy with other things before then.

Comment: account created. :)

Comment: Thank you, arnab.

Comment: Your post got plugged on the main SE blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/the-best-of-blog-overflow-november-2011/